# Apple Mach-O Linker Error when using AVPlayers seekToTime:kCMTimeZero

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I get this error when trying to restart a movie clip.

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
"_kCMTimeZero", referenced from:
Linker command failed with the exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have looked at the build phase and it has `AVFoundation framework` included.

Looked at other `Apple Mach-O Linker Error`, and which made me try doing a clean build, restarting XCode and the OS. But it didn't help.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: post ur error code

Comment: See, I edited the post and added the full error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the `CoreMedia` framework to use `kCMTimeZero`.

Comment: Thanks that solved it! Strange that it's not mentions in the API reference. It looks like it should be in AVFoundation... https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayer/1387741-seektotime

Comment: `AVFoundation` requires `CoreMedia` - but I haven't run into this problem for a while because Xcode seems to automatically import dependencies these days...

Comment: Yeah it didn't feel right and now I saw I already had CoreMedia it before, its kinda essential - but removing it and adding it fixed the issue. :S